# How to make daisy chaining safer?

Tags: power-supply

It seems daisy chaining extension cords is generally not recommended. But assuming you don't have a choice, is there anything that can be done to make the whole thing safer?

Comment: what kind of extension cords are you talking about? ... what voltage and current? ... what are you powering?

Comment: Never load the daisy-chained powerline at 100% of its current rating, instead to derate it by x%, perhaps?

Comment: Unless this is about designing extension cords, questions on how to use electrical devices is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided they're not coiled up on a reel which would cause overheating due to lack of ventilation there are only two real problems:

- Voltage drop due to length of cable. In this regard multiple series-connected extension cables are no worse than one long one of the same wire cross-sectional area of the thinest of the series. Cable voltage drop is easy to calculate when the current is known.
- Contact resistance. Each contact will have some series resistance. This is more problematic as it can vary by brand and by age. Each additional connector gives another potential failure point.

Comment: The voltage drop can be an advantage when the site techs build a transformer that puts out 20V more than specified... ran the longest extensions out over the crane floor and dropped the voltage to stop the HP sprayers overheating.

Comment: One undesirable effect of high resistance from circuit breaker to load: The current caused by a short close to the load may not be high enough to trip the MCB fast. One reason to equip an extension cord with a breaker/fuse of it's own in addition to a TCO/Klixon.

Comment: @greybeard, true, but that's the case independent of chaining which is what this question is about.